# how to work with multiple forms in one asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, forms

I hava a asp.net that I thought is going to have multiple forms.I put a asp panel and added the form to it and validators to controls everyting works.but if I try to put another panel and a form page become invalid.the reason I do this is because any attempt to postback data will trigger all validtors.I know that I can brake each form to each page.but for my design this seems silly.

what im looking for a way to have multiple forms in one page.

or have validators work only on certain situations.

or group validators to work if the button click only happen in the same panel where validators reside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot place more than one **form** tag in a single ASPX page. It is a limitation of **ASP.Net Web Form**.

However, you can fake it with [ValidationGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup(v=vs.110).aspx). For example -

```
<%-- Group One --%>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
    ValidationGroup="One" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
    runat="server"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ValidationGroup="One"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    Text="Textbox one is required." />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1"
    OnClick="Button1_Click"
    Text="Submit"
    ValidationGroup="One" />
<hr/>
<%-- Group Two --%>            
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"
    ValidationGroup="Two" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
    runat="server"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ValidationGroup="Two"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
    Text="Textbox two is required.." />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2"
    OnClick="Button2_Click"
    Text="Submit"
    ValidationGroup="Two" />
```

***Note***: If you want multiple **form** tags in a single page, you might want to look at **ASP.Net MVC**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked as expected. Sorry for the late reply. :D